# c#のMQTTクライアントを教えて下さい

Tags: c#, mqtt

windows 7、8、10をサポートしているMQTTクライアントを教えて頂けないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M2Mqtt
https://m2mqtt.wordpress.com/

.NET Frameworkで動作すると書いてあるので、お書きのWindowsもサポートされていると理解して良いです。
簡単なサンプルコードも紹介されています。
https://opcdiary.net/?p=28785